# Any Known comprehensive tutorial about TeX fonts

Tags: fonts

I am a TeX Live user and I am wondering if there is a comprehensive reference which clearly explains how to go about changing default fonts in LaTeX.

Comment: See „changing fonts“ in https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Fonts , providing several links. Also have a look >here< https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=Changing+fonts , i.e. for using windows fonts, if that‘s your intention.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For beginners, one can simply use a font package, see:

- [A Survey of Free Math Fonts for TeX and LaTeX](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/Free_Math_Font_Survey/survey.html)
- [The LaTeX Font Catalogue](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/)

For advanced user:

- [LaTeX2e font selection (fntguide)](https://www.latex-project.org/help/documentation/fntguide.pdf)
- The LaTeX Companion (2ed), Chapter 7: Fonts and Encodings
- [The LaTeX Graphics Companion (2ed), Supplementary material](http://xml.web.cern.ch/XML/lgc2/tlgc2extra.pdf), Chapter 21: PostScript fonts and beyond

With XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX:

- Package document of [`fontspec`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fontspec)
- [XeTeX Companion](http://xml.web.cern.ch/XML/lgc2/xetexmain.pdf)

Comment: Actually, I am trying to change the default latex fonts and not sure what commands to use in the preamble.

Comment: @isildur Usually, this is done by loading a certain package. Which font do you want to use?

Answer (score 2):

Chapter 8 of *Formatting Information*, section 2 "Using Fonts".
http://latex.silmaril.ie/formattinginformation/typographics.html#fontuse

Comment: This section has been updated (along with the rest of the document) to reflect the growing use of XeLaTeX and TTF/OTF fonts